# Select one from multiple options in UML activity diagram

Tags: uml, modeling, activity

I am very new to UML and UML activity diagrams. my question is suppose in a student course registration system after student successfully login to the system there are 3 options add course, delete course or review courses then how we can implement this in UML activity diagram.

can I use fork here ? but I know fork is used when there is simultaneous actions. this is not simultaneous action. student can either add course delete course or review course. can anyone help me? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an [activity diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html),  if there is a decision which could lead to three different flows, you should use a [decision node](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#decision-node) with guards. This means that only one path is chosen.  The three paths would probably be [merged](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#merge-node) again at some time.

The [fork](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#fork-node), as you rightly noticed,  is for concurrent action. It would mean that all three activities are performed at the same time.  A [join](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#join-node) would then synchronise the three parallel flows before continuing.  This is not what you want here.